# Oracle Adf 12c Adf Data Visualization

Tags: oracle, jdeveloper, oracle-adf-mobile

I have oracle JDeveloper 12c and i want to use graph components .
I don't know where it has been placed and how to create a graph from a view object because when i drag a view object into page, i want to select graph component, it is not available.
can any one suggest me?
thanks

Comment: can u explain more what u want? you are not getting graph components?

Comment: I want to draw a graph but i do not know where is it and how can i creating it .

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this.

Its there **Components** Section in **MAF AMX Data Visualizations** Section...

Answer (score 0):

> When i drag a view object into page, i want to select graph component, it is not available

When you are dragging a data collection from your Data Control into your page, you should get the following menu:

[image]

From there, select "Chart" (or "Hierarchy Viewer", if that is what you mean by "graph") and you will get the Component Gallery dialog to select the style of the chart (or hierarchy viewer):

[image]

Alternatively, if you do not want to automatically data bind the component and do the data binding yourself, you can select "ADF Data Visualizations" from the drop down menu on the Components palette (usually docked at the right border of JDeveloper) and extend the "Common" area. Then you can drag&drop the chart/graph components from there.